# EF Core: Must be reducible node

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not sure why I am getting the error: "Must be reducible node"

This is my query.  I am running Core 2 with EF Core 2.2 (So I should have the fixes that occurred in previous versions)

```
    IQueryable<Gizmo> gizmos = _context.Gizmo;


    IQueryable<GizmoViewModel> dataReferences = (
        gizmos.SelectMany(j => j.DataReferences.Select(r =>
            new GizmoViewModel()
            {
                GizmoId = j.Id,
                DataId = r.DataId
            }
        ))
    );
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply (and sadly) you are hitting one of the current EF Core query translation bugs.

Looks like it's caused by the accessing the outer `SelectMany` lambda parameter inside the inner `Select` expression.

The workaround is to use another `SelectMany` overload having a second lambda with both outer and inner parameters (which I guess is used by C# compiler when converting LINQ query syntax):

```
IQueryable<GizmoViewModel> dataReferences = (
    gizmos.SelectMany(j => j.DataReferences, (j, r) =>
        new GizmoViewModel()
        {
            GizmoId = j.Id,
            DataId = r.DataId
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include DataReferences maybe?

Your code revised:

```
IQueryable<GizmoViewModel> dataReferences = (
        gizmos.SelectMany(j => j.DataReferences.Select(r =>
            new GizmoViewModel()
            {
                GizmoId = j.Id,
                DataId = r.DataId
            }
        ))
.Include(m => m.DataReferences)
```